# Poisson distribution and idd random variables - Proof of an equality

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, poisson-distribution

I want to solve the following task

[image]

The first part was very easy for me.

But I dont know how to solve the second one. I guess I even understood it completely.

I am thankful for any kind of help!

Comment: It seems that several people are down voting my question. It is a good manner to explain why! So I can improve the question and my questions in the future...

Comment: In the second formula that you have to prove there is a λ. What does this λ stand for?

Comment: The parameter of $N$, with $N$ being the upper bound of the sum defining $S$.

Comment: @Stefanos see here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution

Comment: @Benjamin I know what is λ in Poisson, but for the second part you say that $X_r$ are i.i.d. not that they are Poisson!

Comment: @Stefanos They are not poisson but the take a look at the "upper bound" of the sum. It is "N". The same N as in the first part

Comment: @Benjamin Ok, that answers my question. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

- By exchangeability, $E(Sg(S)\mid N)=Nh(N)$ with $h(n)=E(X_1g(X_1+\cdots+X_n))$
- For every $n$, $h(n+1)=E(X_0g(X_0+X_1+\cdots+X_n))$
- Apply the first part of the exercise to $h$